# Prove $a^*(a+b)^*=(a+b)^*$

Tags: regular-expressions

Seems obvious but I need mathematical proof

I tried to go by knowing $R^*=\epsilon + RR^*$ but reached nothing

Comment: I don’t know what rules you have available for manipulating regular sets. Can you justify this calculation? $$(a+b)^*=\epsilon(a+b)^*\subseteq a^*(a+b)^*\subseteq(a+b)^*(a+b)^*=(a+b)^*$$

Comment: I'm new to regular expression and Kleene's algebra and ... but it seems like that your calculation is simply convincing for me

Comment: Basically it just uses the facts that $R^*=R^*R^*$, and that if $R\subseteq S$, then $R^*\subseteq S^*$, which shouldn’t be too hard to prove from any reasonable definition of the notation, so at worst it might require a little more justification for one or two of the steps.

Comment: I think you're right